# Where is jdoc or samples for Carbonado ReplicatedRepositoryBuilder

Tags: java, berkeley-db

Other than bare-bones autogen stuff, I cannot find any documentation or samples that show how to actually use the ReplicatedRepositoryBuilder in Carbonado. In particular, the coding pattern to wire up on both the master and replica process sides.

I am using BDB-JE 5.0.58 with Carbonado 1.2.3. Here is the [typical doc](http://tinyurl.com/l9ht39k) I found.

Questions, assuming I have a master producing process and a second client replica process which continually reads from the one-way replicated repository side:

1. are both processes supposed to have an instance of ReplicatedRepositoryBuilder with roles somehow reversed?
2. can either side execute resync(), even though I only want that driven from the master side?
3. how is replication being done, given these are simple library databases? Is there a listener under the covers on each end, doing what amounts to an in-process thread replaying changes? Is this going on at both ends?
4. is the replica client side supposed to do Repository actions through ReplicatedRepositoryBuilder.getReplicaRepositoryBuilder.build(), or just a normal BDBRepositoryBuilder.build()? I don't see how it is supposed to get a replication-friendly replica Repository handle to work from.

I would be ecstatic at just a simple java code example of both the producer and consumer sides, as they would look sitting in different processes on locahost, showing a make-change => resync => other-side-sees-it sequence.

```
// master producing process
RepositoryBuilder masterBuilder = new BDBRepositoryBuilder(); // ... set some props
RepoitoryBuilder replicaBuilder = new BDBRepositoryBuilder(); // ... set some props
ReplicatedRepositoryBuilder builder = new ReplicatedRepositoryBuilder();
builder.setMaster(true);
builder.setMasterRepositoryBuilder(masterBuilder);
builder.setReplicaRepositoryBuilder(replicaBuilder);
Repository repository = builder.build(); // master CRUD and query done via this handle
... do some CRUD to 'repository' ...
ResyncCapability capability = repository.getCapability(ResyncCapability.class);
capability.resync(MyStorableRecord.class, 1.0, null);

// client reader process
// ?
```